# How do I get SQL Server (2005) to use all ram?

Tags: sql-server-2005, memory, configuration

How do I get SQL Server (2005) to use all ram? (when upgrading ram after SQL Server installation, 16->32gb).

Total DB size are 50gb. ram usage grows and stops at 15.5gb.

Thanks.

Comment: the OS, as well as the DB edition: enterprise, etc is required to answer that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SQL Management studio and connect to the instance
2. Right-click the instance in Object Explorer and select 'Properties'
3. Under 'Memory', see if someone has previously entered a static limit on the RAM usage ('Maximum Server memory in MB').

I'm guessing someone set a limit based on the previous ram and you'll want to either increase it or zero it out and let the server manage itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 64bit Windows and 64bit SQL Server, then you can configure SQL Server to use most of the RAM available - leave a couple of GB for the OS. Make sure that you enable Lock Pages In Memory, and that SQL Server is running on the latest service pack.

If you are using 32bit Windows and 32bit SQL Server, you'll need to enable AWE in SQL Server. You'll also need to consider whether to enable PAE depending on how much RAM you have.

From your comment about it stops around15.5GB, it sounds like you're running 32bit. Watch out - some of the Windows 2003 SP1 editions only allow up to 16GB.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit)

Windows 2008 R2 Standard x64

Comment: Please edit the original question, or leave it as a comment; nobody will see this down here... Thank you and welcome to Server Fault!